# MySQL column mismatch error on very basic query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

(Very common, and I've checked through google, and my issue is that most of the issues are actual comlumn mismatches as it describes)

My location table has "user", "latitude", "longitude", "posttext", user and posttext are both varchar, and lat and long are int.  For the time being, I'm just trying to insert values with user and posttext values.  I've taken the query out of my php, and run it in the SQL part of phpmyadmin and it runs fine, so I'm not sure why I'm getting the error.
A php form supplies the post data from text boxes, and this is the php processing code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 

$username = $_POST['user'];
$textToPost = $_POST['textToPost'];
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","*","*");

if (!$con)
  {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

 mysql_select_db("test");

 $sql= "INSERT INTO location(user, posttext)
 VALUES ('.$username.,.$textToPost.')";

 if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  echo "1 record added";
 mysql_close($con);
 echo $username;
 echo $textToPost;
  ?>
```

So I'm hoping it's a very basic syntax error on my part, but could someone help?

Comment: Inserting data in the query in this way can lead to mysql injection and is extremely unsafe! I suggest you look into mysql_real_escape or parameterized queries once your problem is solved.

Comment: I shall do! It's only for a university project, but as I said below, advice on poor practice is helpful to me, so thanks also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some quotes:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO location(user, posttext)
VALUES ('".$username."','".$textToPost."')";
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP's dots are for string concatenation and shouldn't be there.

Comment: Doh... thank you for your swift help! I'm new to PHP so it's very helpful to have people pointing out inadvisable practices too :)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the query be like this?

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO location(user, posttext)
VALUES ('".$username."','".$textToPost."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
 $sql= "INSERT INTO location(user, posttext)
        VALUES ('".$username."','".$textToPost."')";
```

Remember you MUST always sanitize user input before using it in a query!!
It could be better using prepared statements...